# Swift - Change BG color through an input

Tags: swift, colors, background

I have just started with Swift and I'm wondering if there's any way to take a text input such as red, and then make the background that same color.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myText: UITextField!
@IBAction func myText(_ sender: Any) {
    var responseText: String = myText.text!
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.responseText
}
```

I tried, but it didnt work whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no string initializer for UIColor. You could however write an extension of the UIColor class and add your own initializer to it. But, an easier way would probably just be a switch statement on responseText:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myText: UITextField!
@IBAction func myText(_ sender: Any) {
    var responseText: String = myText.text!
    var bgColor : UIColor
    switch responseText {
    case "Red":
        bgColor = UIColor.red
    // ... etc for every color you want
    }
    self.view.backgroundColor = bgColor
}
```